# QByteArray to unsigned char does not fully copy

Tags: c++, qt

I need to convert the QByteArray of a QImage into unsigned char *.

I do it by:

```
QByteArray data;
QBuffer buffer(&data);

buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
convImage.save(&buffer, "PNG");
buffer.close()

unsigned char *data_image = (unsigned char *)malloc(data.size());
memcpy(data_image, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(data.data()), (unsigned int)data.size());
```

But the result of data_image compared to the QByteArray of the image is like this:

[image]

> data = (QByteArray of the Image)
>
> data_image = unsigned char* from data

I think it's not fully copied. I need the unsigned char* data for an external DLL function.

Comment: How do you expect your debugger to know exactly how many bytes `data_image` points to? Hint: the debugger thinks it's a null-terminated string. And, of course, it's not.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik how do I test it if it successfully copied th whole bytearray?

Comment: @TerribleDog Do you want to test with a debugger?

Comment: Your execute whatever commands your debugger has that explicitly show a specific number of bytes at a given memory location. The commands vary by debugger, but all debuggers implement this basic function. That's what debuggers are for.

Comment: @eyllanesc I just want to know if the unsigned char* gets all the data from the QByteArray object.

Comment: If you don't want to use a debugger, why not just `memcmp(data_image, data.data(), data.size())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not see the full length of the `data_image` array, because it is just a pointer and there is no way to know what its actual size is.
So the debugger is applying some standard rules to stop when it thinks it should. On such rule is to stop on a NULL byte.

If you are using Qt Creator, there are several ways you can force the debugger to show more data:

1. Right-click on the variable you are interested in and select `Change Value Display Format > Array of xxx items`. This is the easiest way, but it is limited as you can only select 10, 100, 1,000 or 10,000 items.
2. Right-click on the variable you are interested in and select `Open Memory Editor > Open Memory View At Object Address`. This is the most versatile as you can see everything in memory, but it might be more confusing if you are not used to play with memory views.

Answer (score 1):

If you have QImage, you can do it simpler:

```
unsigned char *data_image = (unsigned char *)malloc(convImage.sizeInBytes());
memcpy(data_image, convImage.bits(), convImage.sizeInBytes());
```